# Where is post build action on Jenkins - BlueOcean?

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-plugins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-blueocean

I am trying to configure multi-branch pipelines with blueocean.

Previously I was using post build actions to send notifications and triggering other tasks depends on the build status like in here:

[image: post-build action]

Currently I'm looking for similar feature in multi-branch pipelines.

But couldn't find anything regarding to post build actions in old interface and in blueocean pipeline editor.

Jenkins default:

[image: multi-branch pipeline]

BlueOcean:

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since you are using pipeline, the post build actions go into the pipeline code(i.e., Jenkinsfile) configured under 'Build Configuration' in classic view.

[`post` section](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/syntax/#post) can be placed either in pipeline scope or stage scope.

- In pipeline scope, it should be right after stages block.
- In stage scope, `post` section can be placed after any stage block.

Example to call post build action at the end of the pipeline is below.

```
pipeline {
    node any
    stages {
        stage('one') {

        }
        stage('two') {
        }
    } // end of stages block
    post {
        <checkstyle step>
    } //post block in pipeline scope
}
```

Comment: So, it's not available through blueocean interface ?

Comment: @motto There is a jira ticket on the same issue https://issues.jenkins-ci.org/browse/JENKINS-49571